# Angular 6 - problem executing nested .subscribe() "next" function

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I've created an app with user authentication system. Firstly I check if user with given registration e-mail exists and if does not - I call registration service.

register.component.ts

```
registerUser(email: String, password: String) {
  let found = false;
  this.authService.findUser(email).pipe(
    tap(res => { console.log(res.status);
      if (res.status === 202) { found = true; } else if (res.status === 200) { found = false; } else {found = null; }}),
    concatMap(res => {
      console.log(found);
      if (found) {
        this.snackBar.open('E-mail already taken.', 'Ok', { duration: 3000 });
      } else if (!found) {
        this.authService.registerUser(email, password).subscribe(res2 => {
          /* CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE - START */
          console.log(res2.status);
          if (res2.status === 201) {
            this.router.navigate(['/list']);
          } else {
            this.snackBar.open('Unable to add new user.', 'Try later', { duration: 3000 });
          }
          /* CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE - END*/
        });
      } else {
        this.snackBar.open('Checking e-mail address failed.', 'Try later', { duration: 3000 });
      }
      return of(res);
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

The user is registered properly, but the marked code is not executed. **In AuthService - {observe: 'response'} is added to both get (findUser) and post (registerUser) requests.**

Comment: You should rather use `flatMap` than subscribing to the inner observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not subscribe to the inner observable, correct approach is to combine observables to just one and subscribe to it:

```
registerUser(email: String, password: String) {
  this.authService.findUser(email)
    .pipe(
      flatMap(res => {
        let found = null;

        if (res.status === 202) {
          found = true;
        } else if (res.status === 200) {
          found = false;
        }

        console.log(found);

        if (found) {
          this.snackBar.open('E-mail already taken.', 'Ok', { duration: 3000 });

          return of(res);
        }

        return this.authService.registerUser(email, password);
      }),
    )
    .subscribe(res2 => {
      console.log(res2.status);
      if (res2.status === 201) {
        this.router.navigate(['/list']);
      } else {
        this.snackBar.open('Unable to add new user.', 'Try later', { duration: 3000 });
      }
    });
}
```

Note that I also simplified your code, no need for `tap` and `concatMap`. Other thing was that condition for `found` and `!found` - the third `else` branch could never be executed so I removed that as well.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: When user is successfully added, code inside .subscribe() is still not executed. When user already exists 'Unable to add new user' snackbar indeed appears.

Comment: Would be good if you can prepare stackblitz example with your problem. Subscribe handler must be executed when it saves the entity. Are you sure the first request always succeeds? If it errors, than this can never work.

Comment: By adding err => { console.log(err); }); I found out that response is being sent as an error. "HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 201, statusText: "Created", url: "http://localhost:4000/users/register", ok: false, …}"

Comment: Do you return some response? Might be issue with empty response

Comment: SERVER SIDE: user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(user.generateToken());
        }
    });

Comment: Check your network tab if it really returns the response, might be sth else

Comment: The problem was with "(...).send(user.generateToken());". I've attached token to res.json and everything works fine. Thank you for your multiple helpful responses.