# Can't catch error on returned observable from mergeMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my route guard, I am trying to chain multiple requests that needs to be done in specific order to determine if a user is allowed to view a route or not. First, I want to fetch the userRegions, once that is done, I need to fetch the getReadWritePermissions and once that is finally done I return an observable of either true or false depending on if the user should be allowed on the route or not. Both getUserRegions and getWritePermissions returns an Observable of an array.

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.securityService
            .getUserRegions(this.authService.userName)
            .pipe(
                mergeMap((userRegions: Region[]) => {
                    this.regionService.setRegionList(userRegions);
                    return this.permissionsService.getReadWritePermissions(
                        this.authService.userName,
                        userRegions.map(r => r.regionId),
                        undefined
                    );
                }),
                catchError((regionsErr: any) => { // HERE I WANT TO CATCH ANY ERROR FROM getUserRegions()
                    debugger
                    return throwError(regionsErr);
                })
            )
            .pipe(
                map((regionPermissions: RegionPermission[]) => {
                    this.regionService.setRegionPermissionList(regionPermissions);
                    return regionPermissions.some(rp => rp.readWriteAccess.hasReadAccess || rp.readWriteAccess.hasWriteAccess);
                }),
                catchError((permissionsErr: any) => { // HERE I WANT TO CATCH ANY ERROR FROM getReadWritePermissions()
                    debugger
                    return throwError(permissionsErr);
                })
            );
    }
```

What happens is that I am never able to catch an error coming from the getReadWritePermissions() call. The second catchError breakpoint only gets hit when there is an error thrown in the first catchError. I think that this makes sense, but I don't know how to solve my problem of catching any error from the getReadWritePermissions(). The route guard works as intended, so that's not the problem. It's just that the getReadWritePermissions() method calls an API, and if the api-response is 404, 401 etc. (eg an error) I want to be able to catch this.

What exactly is happening here? Which one is the inner observable and which one is the outer one? Why am I not able to catch the error of the returned observable from the mergeMap, and how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Why are you using `mergeMap` instead of `map`? Also, there's no need for 2 separate `.pipe(`, this call all be one single pipe.

Comment: @Viqas I am using mergeMap as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345129/6140358) saying that the observables should be combined into one. Please enligthen me as too why this is not the desired way? If i change the mergeMap to map, the second map in the pipe now receives an observable of an array, instead of the array that it needs. Please be descriptive in your answer as I am not very familiar with rxjs. Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, I've exactly the same problem with mergeMap, the way emmep is doing the catchError works fine in angular resolvers, but I'm still having this error: No overload matches this call, anyone knows why is that?